# Thin Content Penalty

Tags: google

I just got a thin content penalty from Google. I was not sure what that meant, so after research I contacted a SEO expert who told me I was scraping websites and I needed to stop. The problem is, I am not scraping websites, I have 17 websites that are scraping me. I also have a google blogger that has decided to run a blog with my website name with all of my articles for the past seven months. I am not sure what to do, or if this is in fact what I got a penalty for. Does Google make mistakes like this? Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This isn't thin content. Its duplicate content.

Comment: If you have a Google Webmaster Tools account you can use https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/dmca-dashboard and file a complaint of stolen content. I would recommend this especially for the Blogger (my assumption) site which is a Google property. On top of this, get an attorney to write a cease and desist letter (or equivalent) to the site owners and carbon copy the webhosts, and registrars of the sites that are stealing your content. The webhosts and registrars should and must terminate the accounts or face culpability.